# Android ViewStub manage replace inner Views

Tags: android, android-inflate, viewstub

i am testing with the `ViewStub` Android component. I am able to inflate a `View` and replace by a new one, but when i perform a replace of the existing `View` by a new one, i suspect that the destroyer is never called at the old replaced Views. Here is an example code of my logic:

```
protected void testInflateReplaceViewStub(){
    //case inflating a View...
    View viewInflated = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.container_view, this); //container View
    ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.view_stub_impl); //view inside layout
    viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.container_view); //fill with some content
    View viewStubInflated = viewStub.inflate();
    //end inflating the first ViewStub

    //case replacing above View by a new one...
    viewStubInflated.invalidate(); //this should destroy old inner Views??
    viewInflated = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.container_view, this);
    viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.new_content);//fill new content
    viewStubInflated = viewStub.inflate();
    //end replacing inflating
}
```

I'd like to force destroying all the old replaced `Views`.

Answer (score 1):

One you inflate the `ViewStub` it disappears of the hierarchy and you cannot use it again:

> After inflation of the layout resource "mySubTree," the ViewStub is
>   removed from its parent.

See [ViewStub documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html).

Try using `include` or even `FrameLayout`, depend on your needs.